# What are phenomenological models and ab-initio models in terms of dense matter?

Tags: nuclear-physics, neutron-stars

I've tried to grasp the concept of phenomenological and microscopical ab-initio models when it comes to EOS of neutron star matter . I can understand the meaning of them in general, but I find it difficult to understand when the *phenomena* is so theoretical and microscopic itself.

In particular I'm trying to understand what category Skyrme models and RMF models fall under, but help to understand the difference in general would be much appreciated.

Comment: “I can understand the meaning of them in general” — do you mean that you understand what is meant by the labels “phenomenological” and “ab initio”? If so, it’s unclear what you’re asking.